# Magento XML - Difference cms_index_index and cms_index_defaultindex

Tags: magento, layout, content-management-system

When looking at the Magento app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/cms.xml file, I noticed two different handles:
`<cms_index_index>` and `<cms_index_defaultindex>`

In other stackoverflow questions, the handle `<cms_index_index>` is used in the local.xml for applying changes to the Magento Homepage.

However, I wasn't able to find the use of the `<cms_index_defaultindex>` handle.
What does this handle do, what is the difference compared to the `<cms_index_index>` handle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you please up-vote the answer, if you accept it? Up-voting useful answers helps other users to identify the most useful information, and rewards people answering your question by increasing their reputation score. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<cms_index_index>` is your CMS home-page, as set in Magento Admin (system config).

`<cms_index_defaultindex>` is the page rendered when the one CMS page set as the "homepage" in your Magento is not available. As you can see from the code of Mage_Cms_IndexController class, defaultIndexAction method is the "404 Not Found" page.